# Is it possible to add salesforce as an identity provider to ACS

Tags: azure, salesforce, claims-based-identity, acs

As The ACS Management Portal doesn't provide built-in support for configuring salesforce as an identity provider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185971.aspx

Is there any way to add salesforce as an identity provider manually to ACS?

Thread: [Does Azure ACS support saml 2.0 IdPs like Salesforce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811626/does-azure-acs-support-saml-2-0-idps-like-salesforce) doesn't come to any conclusion on the matter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't add SalesForce as IdP in Azure Access Control Service.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Unfortunately, ACS doesn't support SAML-P identity providers at this time.

Answer (score 0):

How about add a custom STS as identity provider, in these STS use saml2.0 idps?

Answer (score 0):

Ping me (through the contact page on http://blog.maartenballiauw.be), this is the thing I'm trying to solve with www.socialsts.com.